# Console interface to Rational ClearQuest

Tags: windows, command-line

There's "cleartool" - console interface for ClearCase.
How to interact with ClearQuest from console?

Example of sequense I want to be able to script:

1. Open ClearQuest
2. Press "New UnitOfWork" toolbar item
3. Fill the GUI form of text fields and combo boxes.
4. Press "OK" button

I don't want the command line interface to be too deviant from GUI.

I expect it to be something like:

```
clearquesttool (server,database,user,password) add --type=UnitOfWork --workload=30m --project="Some name I see in GUI" --activity="Defect fixing"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the ClearQuest tool [`cqtool`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.cqtool.doc/topics/cqtool_cmd_ref_container.htm) which has a **[submit](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cqhelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.cqtool.doc/topics/r_submit.htm)** subcommand.  It has the following syntax:

> submit [common options] [-field name 
>   value [ value value ...] ] [-f/ield
>   name  value [ value value ... ] [-ask]
>   [-type record_type]

So you would want to do something like this:

```
cqtool submit -type UnitOfWork -f workload 30m -f project "Some name I see in GUI" -f activity "Defect fixing"
```

**Update:** cqtool is available on UNIX platforms only in version 2003; in 7.1 it is available on all supported platforms - [ClearQuest FAQ](http://www.samecs.com/how_do_i/ClearQuest/ClearQuest%20how%20do%20I.htm#_Toc245769909)

Comment: Yes, we have version 2003. But coLinux should satisfy "UNIX platforms" requirement, shouldn't it?
(looking for where to download it)

Comment: If you can get it to install on coLinux, I would expect it to work just as it would on any other Linux.